# map a method over list of different objects

Tags: python, inheritance, mapping

I would like to map a method over a list of objects instantiating different classes. All the objects inherit from the same base class and define a method of the desired name.

To make it clearer consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def foo (self):
        return self.x

class B(A):
    def foo (self):
        return self.x+1

class C(A):
    def foo (self):
        return self.x-1
```

Now consider a list of objects instantiating the classes B and C. I would like to do something like that:

```
result = []
for obj in [B(1), C(1)]:
    result.append(obj.foo())
```

How would you proceed to map the method foo on each element of the list? Is it at all possible? The best I could come up with is something like that:

```
map(A.foo, [B(1), C(1)])
```

but clearly it doesn't return my desired result. How can I specify the method related to the object?

I hope I made myself clear.

**NB**: I work primarily with Python2.7, but I would equally be interested in solutions valid for "newer" versions.

Comment: You're missing the call to A's __init__ form B and C, __init__ is not called implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.foo(), [B(1), C(1)])
>>> [2, 0]
```

The lambda function will take each object in the list and call foo() on that object. Thus the resulting list will have the results returned by the corresponding object's foo().

Answer (score 4):

`Map(A.foo, [B(1), C(1)])` is basically doing `A.foo(B(1))` and `A.foo(C(1))` which isn't what you are looking for.

Using your classes from above, I would just do:

```
In: objs = [B(1), C(1)]
In: [x.foo() for x in objs]
Out: [2, 0]
```

Amjith has a pure map implementation if you'd prefer that.

Answer (score 3):

For most practical purposes, I'd recommend @AlG's list comprehension, but you can do this with `map` as well:

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.methodcaller("foo"), [B(1), C(1)])
[2, 0]
```